# Where to find the Monero blockchain by itself?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, blockchain, synchronization

as many of you know it takes a huge amount of time to sync-up to a full Monero node. So what I want to do is download the blockchain(or at least most of it) so it is much quicker; and then point that to the source of the blockchain later in the terminal (I'm using a Macbook Air.) I can't find any links to the raw blockchain anywhere, does anyone know where I can find it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The blockchain can be downloaded here: https://downloads.getmonero.org/blockchain.raw

Note that hours of processing power is still required to verify the blockchain when you import it. You can disable this verification by following the guide here: https://getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/importing_blockchain.html

Warning: The whole point of verification is that you can trust that the blockchain you download is not compromised. Turning verification off is not recommended.

Comment: Yes, disable verification so your blockchain can be compromised by a fake download.

Comment: @user36303 I only put that in because the question was about attempting to speed up the sync, and the questioner may not understand that the download of the blockchain is not necessarily the major bottleneck. I'll add a warning to the answer.